# Are there any file managers out there for Angular4?

Tags: angular, file-management, file-manager, responsive-filemanager

I'm looking for a file manager that I can use in my Angular4 App (this is a work related question). While browsing I could only find AngularJS file managers. Do they not yet exist for Angular4 or is there another way to solve my problem?

Comment: what do you mean by file managers ?

Comment: We are looking for a solution for our AngularJS file manager, which is a storage for files, where we can upload files inside folders (visual in the front-end) and which uses a filetree so we can see the structure of the folders and the files inside them. We now use this: https://github.com/joni2back/angular-filemanager